# EclipseLink JPA issue with SINGLE_TABLE @Inheritance not inheriting

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I have 3 classes extending an abstract base class, all with the same formal structure.  They were all constructed and working properly with a Hibernate/Spring data harness and have been for a few months now in a production system.  However, Hibernate does not support discriminator column multitenancy out of the box, so I have been working on the transition to EclipseLink 2.5.2, which supposedly does.

I've spent at least a day trying to get the following to work - and apologies if I can't list all of the configurations I've tried in that time, as they were legion.  I'm hoping that this present configuration will at least target what's wrong for someone more familiar with EclipseLink than I am.  Base class, minus accessors and constructors:

```
@Converters(
    @Converter(name = "UUIDConverter", converterClass = UUIDToStringConverter.class)
)
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "label_type_definitions")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "scope", columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
public abstract class LabelTypeDefinition implements LabelType {

    @Id
    @Convert("UUIDConverter")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 40, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @UuidGenerator(name = "uuid")
    protected final UUID id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    protected String description;

...
}
```

The subclasses.  Tree:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "TREE")
public class LabelTreeDefinition extends LabelTypeDefinition implements LabelTree {
    ....
}
```

Scenario:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SCENARIO")
public class LabelScenarioDefinition extends LabelTypeDefinition implements LabelScenario {
    ...
}
```

Node:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "NODE")
public class LabelNodeDefinition extends LabelTypeDefinition implements LabelNode {
    ...
}
```

The LabelType interface extends Serializable and my own Identifiable and describes the accessor contract for the model (interfaces for models = not my design, a consequence of a separate Maven project for API baked in by my predecessor).  The interfaces LabelTree/Node/Scenario all extend LabelType without adding to the contract.

The problem: when this configuration constructs my database, it ignores the table specification and does not build a scope column.

```
LABELTREEDEFINITION
    id
    name
    description
LABELNODEDEFINITION
    id
    name
    description
LABELSCENARIODEFINITION
    id
    name
    description
```

To me this means it is completely ignoring the @Inheritance annotation and is doing so silently.  I can force it to build all of that in and make it look superficially correct by adding @Table annotations to each subclass and including a scope column (the latter was how it was built when using Hibernate), but then of course all of my Spring Data queries ignore the discriminator.

Could all of this be a consequence of implementing the different interfaces?  If so, that worries me as it seems extremely fragile.  It seems to me this is all otherwise identical to what's described eg. here (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance).  Is there something I have missed or some quirk of EclipseLink I have overlooked?

Comment: Make sure that all your annotations are from package `javax.persistence` and not from a Hibernate package (some have the same name).

Comment: Thanks, yep, all are javax.persistence.  Except for the @Converter annotations, the javax.persistence versions of which seem not to work ("undeclared" exception at runtime) - I actually don't like this particularly either, as I'd rather not have implementation-specific dependencies in this model code.  At any rate all mentions of hibernate specific annotations have been excised.

Comment: I should mention I've just gone through the work of separating out the contracts from the models (ie. the models no longer use "implements X" except for LabelTypeDefinition) ... and it made no difference.  Which is good from a fragility standpoint, but the problem remains.

Comment: The answer was twofold, persistence.xml for the abstract base class and \@Entity instead of \@MappedSuperclass.  Figured all of this out by running org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor through a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I figured out the problem by painfully running through EclipseLink's code in my debugger.  I happened to notice that when it was trying to assign the inheritance in org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor, it wasn't finding the superclass LabelTypeDefinition.  This was not a problem for Hibernate, so it didn't occur to me that the abstract base class also had to be included in persistence.xml, ie.

```
<persistence-unit name="[MYPROJECT]" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
    <class>com.[MYPROJECT].persistence.labeltype.LabelNodeDefinition</class>
    <class>com.[MYPROJECT].persistence.labeltype.LabelTreeDefinition</class>
    <class>com.[MYPROJECT].persistence.labeltype.LabelScenarioDefinition</class>
    <class>com.[MYPROJECT].persistence.labeltype.LabelTypeDefinition</class>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

However, when I ran it through a second time I discovered it *still* could not find the class.  As a Hail Mary, I replaced @MappedSuperclass with @Entity in my parent class and it all worked.

Now the first part of the fix was a little bit of a headslapper, ie. I should have thought of the possibility EclipseLink required more explicit configuration than Hibernate.  However the second strikes me as a bug, particularly since I've found documentation in numerous places (including the eclipse wiki link I posted above) that suggests it should work.  And because semantically it seems more correct: my abstract base class is not, in fact, an "entity" in that no LabelType objects ever get persisted as such.  But it is a superclass that's "mapped" by my entities.

Comment: Inheritance in entities is different and conflicts with the MappedSuperclass designation.  MappedSuperclasses cannot themselves be queried upon or referenced, while when you mark an abstract Entity with Inheritance you are stating you can use this class through out and have JPA figure out the specific subclass to return.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but you've said two things here.  One I understand.  That's the second part about the meaning of Entity/Inheritance/abstract. I would still argue that there should be a specific annotation for the situation that reduces the combinatorics related to applying various annotations in what looks to me (and I can't imagine I'm alone there) an oxymoronic way.  Regardless, this part isn't worth discussing because I'm not writing JPA, just trying to write code that works within its confines.

Comment: But I don't understand why the Inheritance annotation conflicts with MappedSuperclass.  I have abstract MS objects that hold common properties (eg. Id) for a variety of entities. They aren't mapped to data, just supply properties to persisted subclasses.  IMO, LabelTypeDefinition plays an exactly analogous role: supply properties but not dictate role in app. But labeling it Entity semantically indicates to me an expectation it is instantiable on its own, with the inherited classes adding meaning (eg. User => Developer).  Is your comment specifically about JPA design or something deeper?

Comment: My wording wasn't precise, it doesn't conflict, it is more that it just doesn't apply and is likely ignored.  Under the description of the inheritance annotation it states "The Inheritance annotation defines the inheritance strategy to be used for an entity class hierarchy.
It is specified on the entity class that is the root of the entity class hierarchy."  A MappedSuperclass is not an entity, it cannot be queried etc like an entity, and so cannot be the root of an entity inheritance structure defined by the inheritance annotation.

Comment: Every Entity that inherits from your mapped superclass needs to be made the root of its own inheritance structure, with its own inheritance annotation/designation.